# What kind of collection class to get position in array?

Tags: java, list, object

I have the following situation and I am asking for a suggestion to do it "right" in Java.

I have an `ArrayList` which contains a list of objects (let's call it object **A**),

each object is comprised of two other objects, let's call them

- object **X**
- and object **Y**

[image: class A diagram]

Now in my code a method returns an instance of the object Y.

Now I need the index in the `ArrayList` where I find the same object Y.

Please how do I do it, without doing terrible loops?

What could I use instead of an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Hve you tried the indexOf method? Unless these objects are of different types http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: loop through your array and do `(keyY.equals(array[index].getY()){ return index;}`

Comment: @nEm hi nEm, thanks, correct me if I am wrong, but that would work if I had an instance of object A; I have an object Y instead :-((

Comment: How are you using the method to get the object Y then? Can you map object Y to A?

Comment: @JigarJoshi thanks Jigar, but I am looking for a more "elegant" solution ;-)

Comment: I think I understand... you want to find another object A which has the same Object Y in it?

Comment: @nEm I could indeed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a List, finding an Object in the list with a certain value just requires a loop looking at each object, period.

A more natural choice for the problem would be to put your objects into a Map, using your Y as a key and the object as the value:

```
Map<Y, A> map = new HashMap<>();

void putA(A a) {
    map.put(a.Y, a);
}

A getA(Y y) {
    return map.get(y);
}
```

Note that the map only stores one A for each distinct value of Y. Its not suited to associate multiple A's with one Y. For that you would use a map of Set or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

basic approach: loop through your array and do

```
(keyY.equals(array[index].getY()){ return index;}
```

more elegant solution would be to create a data structure as you fill array `Map<Y, Integer>` that maps instances of Y to index in array (or some more meaningful mapping based on your real usecase) and make sure you implement proper `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Y`

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try indexOf... it might or it might not work on some objects, but it depends on the data members.

Comment: array doesn't have `indexOf()` method, and if you use `ArrayList` then `indexOf()` uses `equals()` internally so it will only work if you implement equals to just compare `y` which isn't good, and it is internally iterating through array